# How to show diffrent color button in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Here i did all correct after return the datas in index page display in that value i need to do one more thing extra what is means while returning data **booking_status=="1"** means i want to show red color button and button is unclickable(class="btn btn-primary) suppose " **booking_status=="0"** means i want to show green color button(class="btn btn-primary).in **console.log(res); i am getting like this**

```
count:2
data:Array[2]
0:Object
1:Object

booking_status:"1"

id:"2"

pg_id:"1"

rent:"4000"

room_number:"Room 2"

room_sharing:"2"


----------


booking_status:"1"

id:"3"

pg_id:"1"

rent:"4000"

room_number:"Room 3"

room_sharing:"2"
```

```js
<script>
function showDiv(toggle){
var sharing=$("#sharing").val();
   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
   url: "pg_details.php",
      data: "sharing_id="+sharing,
   success: function(data) {
   var res =jQuery.parseJSON(data);
   console.log(res);
   $.each(res.data, function(key, value) {
  var booking_status = value.booking_status;
  console.log(booking_status);//i am getting 1 here
  
  if(booking_status == "1"){
    $("#book").removeClass("btn-success").addClass("btn-danger");
    $("#book1").removeClass("btn-success").addClass("btn-danger");
    el = $('[data-id='+value.pg_name +']');
   
    if (el.length) 
    {
     // console.log(booking_status);
    
     el.find('.btnmar').append(' <a href="register.php?roomid='+value.id +'&&pg_id='+value.pg_id+'&&amount='+value.room_rent+'&&room_number='+value.room_number+'&&advance='+value.advance_amount+'"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="book" style=" width: 71px; ">'+value.room_number+'</button></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;');
     } 
     else 
     {
     //console.log(booking_status);
      var htmlString =  '<div id="toggle" data-id="'+value.pg_name +'"> <div class="container" style=" margin-bottom: 30px;"><div class="row"><h4 style="margin-left:15px;">'+value.pg_name +'</h4><div class="col-sm-10"><div class="btn-group btnmar"><a href="register.php?roomid='+value.id +'&&pg_id='+value.pg_id+'&&amount='+value.room_rent+'&&room_number='+value.room_number+'&&advance='+value.advance_amount+'"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success" style=" width: 71px; id="book1"">'+value.room_number+'</button></a>&nbsp;&nbsp; </div></div><div class="col-sm-2"> <div class="panel-group"><div class="panel panel-primary"><div class="panel-heading"> Premium Facility</div><div class="panel-body" style=" padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px;"><i class="fa fa-television" aria-hidden="true" style="margin-right:15px;"></i>T.V.</div><div class="panel-body" style=" padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px;"><i class="fa fa-wifi" aria-hidden="true" style="margin-right:15px;"></i>Wifi</div><div class="panel-body" style=" padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px;"><i class="fa fa-bed" aria-hidden="true" style="margin-right:15px;"></i>Bed</div><div class="panel-body" style=" padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px;"><i class="fa fa-shopping-basket" aria-hidden="true" style="margin-right:15px;"></i>Washing Machine</div> </div> </div> </div></div></div></div>';
     $(".view_room").prepend(htmlString);
     }
  }
  
   
  });
   }
    });
 
 }
</script>

pg_details.php

<?php
include_once("admin/config.php");
include("functions.php");
$sharing=$_POST['sharing_id'];//Getting Sharing Value
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM rooms WHERE room_sharing='$sharing'");
$count = mysql_num_rows($sql);
if($count > 0){
 while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
  $row['pg_name'] = Getpgname($row['pg_id']);
  $data[]= $row;
 }
 $pg_type= array("return"=>1,"count" =>$count,"data" =>$data);
    echo $pg_type = json_encode($pg_type);
}else{
 $pg_type= array("return"=>0,"count" =>0,"data" =>"");
    echo $pg_type = json_encode($pg_type);
}
?>
```

```html
<div class="view_room"></div>
```

Comment: So, I want to be sure I understand... you want to change from `btn-primary` to `btn-success` via a jquery statement?

Comment: yes but condtion is booking_status=="1" means btn-danger ,booking_status=="0" means btn-success

Comment: Please see my updated answer but still i can't get correct answer,button color not change

Answer (score 1):

The basic logic of this is as such, for `jquery` plus `bootstrap`:

```
$("#idFieldName").removeClass("btn-primary").addClass("btn-success");
```

What this does is:

This determines what `id="fieldname"`

```
$("#idFieldName")
```

This removes the current `btn-primary`:

```
removeClass("btn-primary")
```

This adds the `btn-success`:

```
removeClass("btn-success")
```

and the two periods in-between are basically "keep doing this next thing" kind of statement.

You will need to obviously deal with the if/else logic for your `booking_status` but that is the easier part.

Answer (score 0):

The cleaner way you can put the operational `&&` like this example

```
if (el.length &&  booking_status=="1" ) {
   //your true statement
   // append your button danger here
} 
else {
   // if booking status=="0"
   // append your button primary
}
```

Here is [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/owtfo05m/) make you more understand what i'm trying to explain.

Comment: idk which variable calling that booking status. if you can get post here.

Comment: Please see my updated answer but still i can't get correct answer,button color not change

Comment: wait, can u write here where is booking status variable